# we installed ParadoxLabs AuthorizeNetCim payment method but not working in Celigo

Tags: magento-1.9

we installed ParadoxLabs AuthorizeNetCim payment method which having code "authnetcim".

One of our customer choose above payment method and place order after celigo sync that order to thier system "Celigo Software".

When we generated shipment using Celigo Software it gives error  "authnetcim" such "Payment method not available"

Can you help ASAP...